# Sql query to give a bunch of registered customers points

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise

I am wanting to run a query on my Magento 2.3.4 Enterprise to give registered customers of a specific customer group id x number of reward points. Using Magento's default reward point feature.
However I am not sure what the query would be. Wondering if someone might have a tutorial on the database scheme the reword feature uses?

Comment: You shouldn't write a query for this. Magento is an event based system and you'd be missing several essential events. It would be better to write a script to which you could pass an array of customer id => points to add.

Comment: Thank you. However that does not answer my question. Since even if I write a phtml file that when loaded runs the query I still am unclear of the query (specific tables) involved.

Comment: You wouldn't do this in an phtml file. You'd most likely do it in a data patch file. Additionally, when using the proper models/resource models you don't really need to know the tables. You need to know which API methods to use. But the two tables would be magento_reward (thats the main one you care about) and magento_reward_history because it would be wise to record the "where did those points come from"

Answer (score 0):

The two tables involved are `magento_reward` and `magento_reward_history`. However, it is not advisable to just run a query directly in the database. Anytime that thought comes to mind, its typically not the right way to go and definitely not a best practice for a variety of reasons.

The best course of action would be to review some of the observer files inside the `vendor/magento/module-reward/Observer` directory and see how Magento is issuing points for various events. You can use that methodology in your data patch.